# Concatenate based off user Input

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have a excel file that hase 4 Sheets. 3 Sheets for Data based off of the ORG of that Data. Then 1 Sheet for User Input. Each of the Orgs sheets have up to 20 Columns A-T of Data that I want to concatenate. So basically if a user puts a value in Col A on the Input Sheeet the 3 other Sheets in COl U would then fill in. So for Example Say Col A has a value and COL F and Col H. Those COLS would then Concatenate in COL U on the 3 Other sheets.

I currently have a Formula that does this in Excel with a bunch of IF statements but this is very slow As the Sheets of a few of the data sets are very large. One with over 140K rows of Data. So I am hoping to find a way with VBA to check which Cols in the Input Sheet are Filled and Then concatenate in the Data Sheets based off that. I have a Search button and have automatic formulas off so the Search buttton currently then calculates all the formulas. So I can run this code off of that hopefully. but I don't know much about VBA and if it would speed this process up much more then it is currently as it can take a little while currently. I have attached some Screenshots of the Input and Data Sheets. Data being hidden though.

I currently do some lookups after the Excel formulas run with those Concatination to return values to the User. Both ORG 1 & 2 have 20 Columns A:T, Org 3 has 18 A:R. so thats the Only Differenece in the 3 Data Sheets

Once again all i am trying to do is concatenate whatever Columns the user inputs into each Sheet which has thousands of rows on each Sheet.

Input Sheet

[image]

What ORG 1&2 Sheet look like

[image]

What ORG 3 Sheet Looks like

[image]

Any help is appreciated. I have looked on here and seen VBA concatenation but nothing quite similar to this task.

Comment: VBA is typically going to be _slower_ than an equivalent native function.  Of course, there might just be a much smarter way to approach it.

Comment: You could use the `Worksheet.Change` event.  Set it to check if `Target` (cell/cells where the change occurred) is in the user input range/column.  If so, update the value of concatenation cell in the same row (or if `Target` is multiple cells then check and update for each cell in `Target`).  See [Worksheet.Change event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) from Microsoft.